# Take a Python list as parameter and modifiy the list parameter by swapping its first and last elements

Tags: python

This can be an infinite list of numbers, So far I can't figure out how to switch the first and last of the list without knowing where the list ends.
If the list is (1,2,3,4,5) the output should be (5,2,3,4,1)
Really stuck, first language, wondering if anyone can offer some help!

```
def swapFirstAndLast(list):
     for position in range(0, len(list)):
         list[position] = 
         list[position] =
```

Comment: If it's an infinite list of numbers, then the last element is not computationally accessible i.e. there is no last element. I think that assumption is a little ambiguous.

Comment: avoid the name list` as `list()` is a Python builtin to create list objects.

Comment: What happens if `list` = `[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't mean an infinite list of numbers, that wouldn't fit into memory, but rather, an list of any possible size. Well, you always know the last position of a list in Python. It will always be the length of the list minus one:

```
my_list[len(my_list) - 1]
```

Python `list` objects also handily support *negative indexing*, so the above could be shortened to:

```
my_list[-1]
```

So to swap the first and last elements, simply do:

```
my_list[0], my_list[-1] = my_list[-1], my_list[0]
```

Note, the above is a nice little feature of python, often in languages you are forced to swap elements using a temporary variable:

```
temp = my_list[0]
my_list[0] = my_list[-1]
my_list[-1] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap_first_and_last(some_list):
     some_list[0], some_list[-1] = some_list[-1], some_list[0]
```

will work like below

```
>>> L1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> swap_first_and_last(L1)
>>> L1
[3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal what would you return? Seems like returning `None` is reasonable here.

Comment: Ye, no it's legit. :)

Comment: Lists are mutable, when passed as parameter I am actually changing the original, no need to `list_b = func(list_a)`. `func(list_a)` will do by side effect. But there is also a point in avoiding implicit actions like that for readability (or safety)

Comment: Yes, I am just in habit of returning functions. Something I can point out is that your function name does not abide by pep8 conventions :P `swap_first_and_last`

Comment: You are right, actually didn't even notice, just copy pasted all around from question :) I am editing that.